# Permutations: If I know $\alpha$ and the cycle structure of $\alpha\beta$, can I find $\gamma$ for which $\gamma\beta$ also has this cycle structure?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cryptography, permutations

Suppose we have two permutations $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (of a set $S$ of size $|S|=n$), and I know $\alpha$ and the cycle structure of $\alpha\beta$.  But I don't know $\beta$.

> Can I find a permutation $\gamma \neq \alpha$ such that $\gamma\beta$ has the same cycle structure of $\alpha\beta$?

This is an avenue of attack for a secret sharing scheme I'm thinking about.  Basically, I want to lie about my permutation to fool another participant.

If the above is not possible deterministically, I could pick one at random.  I can improve my chance over picking uniformly at random, by choosing $\gamma$ to have the same sign as $\alpha$.  Can I do better?

I have a particular cycle structure in mind (two $(n/2)$-cycles), if it makes any difference.  In the secret sharing scheme $\beta$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\mathrm{Sym}(S)$.

Comment: You mean, you want $\alpha \beta$ to be the product of two $n/2$ disjoint cycles?

Comment: That's right: I know $\alpha\beta$ decomposes into two disjoint $(n/2)$-cycles.  And I want to find $\gamma$ so $\gamma\beta$ also decomposes into two disjoint $(n/2)$-cycles.

Comment: I may be on the wrong track, but there is a trivial case here. This is when $\beta$ is an $n/2$-cycle, and both $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are $n/2$-cycles disjoint from $\beta$. So some hypothesis has to be added to de-trivialize the thing. I am reluctant to add my own hypothesis here, as it might not fit into the full picture you have in mind. Is there any natural hypothesis you could think of adding?

Comment: You're right: I should have mentioned that these are permutations of a set of size $n$.  I also can add that $\beta$ is a random permutation.  (Edited into the Q now.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible except $\gamma$ being a cyclic shift of $\alpha$ (which is essentially the same permutation).

The reason is the set of all permutations form the symmetric group $S_n$ (where $n$ is the size of your alphabet set). Now you are trying for $\gamma \beta = \alpha \beta$. But $\beta$ will have an inverse (since it belongs to the group $S_n$) so cancellation law forces you to have $\alpha=\gamma$.

However if you want $\beta\gamma = \alpha \beta$, then you can go with any conjugates of $\alpha$.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of this. The question is about the cycle structure of the permutation, not the permutation itself. The answer is that sometimes this is not possible and sometimes it is, and that is obvious, for instance if $\beta=\alpha^{-1}$ then this is not possible, and if $\alpha$ is a transposition and $\beta=id$ then this is possible. But the interesting question is about "random" $\beta$.

Comment: cycle structure means the representation of a permutation using cycles. This is same as knowing the permutation. Perhaps what you are referring to is cycle "type" where you only know the lengths of the cycles and not the cycles itself.

Comment: @AnuragA Who are you to impose that narrow meaning on the word "structure" without the assent of others? Googling "cycle structure of permutations" returns plenty of results where "structure" is used the same way as "type." The bizarre triviality of the question on your interpretation should have clued you in to what meaning the OP is really using.

Comment: @blue you seem to take it too personally. As for who am I? it is irrelevant for a definition's validity. I would suggest you to look up any decent text in Algebra and you will see the difference between the usage of "structure" and "type". Just because some people use it interchangeably doesn't make it correct. Moreover google has lot of stuff all of which may not be correct.

Comment: Then correct the OP's terminology - if it is indeed well-established that there is only one correct definition and the authors on the search results are wrong - instead of answering what you know is not the question that they are asking. Why deliberately choose to answer the wrong question and stay silent on the fact the OP has misspoke until questioned yourself? That seems inexplicable to me.

Comment: I've never before seen "cycle structure" used to mean "the representation of a permutation using cycles". The meaning of "cycle structure" that I've seen is a list of how many cycles of each length occur in the representation of a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles.  (So two permutations have the same cycle structure iff they are conjugate in the symmetric group.)